# Is it bad to have a for loop without an increment or decrement?

Tags: c++, c, for-loop

Sometimes I need to write a loop in C/C++ where there is an initialization followed by a condition.

I like how this looks,

```
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i == 0 && j == 0;) {
    // condition fails at some point
}
```

more than this.

```
int i = 0, j = 0;
while (i == 0 && j == 0) {
    // condition fails at some point
}
```

Granted that this is personal code so noone can judge me. Will the compiler make it so that they are the same thing?

Comment: Variable scopes are different.

Comment: I'm assuming that i and j can only be used within the for loop; that's fine in my case then.

Comment: It certainly *can* generate synonymous code. For example, [for-loop](https://godbolt.org/g/0cOJ8B), and [while-loop](https://godbolt.org/g/OxO9yL). That doesn't mean a compiler *must* generate identical code. You can always check for yourself by using both, then disassembling and compare.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `for` loop if you **don't need** the variables `i` and `j` after the loop.

Use the `while` loop if you **need** the variables `i` and `j` after the loop.

Comment: You can declare and define `i` and `j` outside `for`.

Comment: @Igor. Yes, one can do that. However, for such a use case, the additional syntactic elements of the `for` loop serve no purpose at all. A `while` loop will be cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't use the third clause in the `for` loop (for increment/decrement/whatever), you're not paying for it.

Compiler is perfectly able to generate the same code in both cases, so your `for` code is valid and probably even preferable due to the scope argument that other people have made.

In fact the C++ standard [explicitly requires](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.for#1) these two options to be equivalent, so it's not even a question of choice for the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

It is neither good nor bad.

There is a difference, as noted in comment by BLUEPIXY and answer by R Sahu, that the scope of variables is different.    The `while` form allows the variables `i` and `j` to be used after the loop, and for `for` form does not (albeit, that can be changed quite easily by declaring the variables before the `for` statement).

Only you can decide if the variables `i` and/or `j` need to be accessed after the loop.   As a rule of thumb, however, I would suggest not allowing them to be accessed after the loop unless there is a specific need to (i.e. limit their scope as much as practical).

If this code is in a function of its own, and the function returns immediately after the loop, then there is only a difference if the function's return value depends on `i` or `j`.

You might want to look closely at how the variables `i` and `j` are being updated within the loop body, and consider if that logic can be moved into the `for` statement itself.   Depending on complexity of the loop body, that may or may not be possible.    That can help make it more clear to the reader the conditions under which the loop is actually updating those variables.   And considering whether to move updating outside the loop body will force you to consider whether the loop body itself can be written in a simpler way (given a choice between two ways of achieving the same result, always prefer a simpler one, as it is easier to understand, easier to get right, and easier to maintain in future).

Given that you have a loop that depends on the values of two variables, consider whether a nested loop (one working over `i` and one working over `j`) is possible.